# How to Use Pre-Trained CNN models in Python

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So basically I am trying to use a pre-trained VGG CNN model. I have downloaded model from the following website:

http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/pretrained/

which has given me a image-vgg-m-2048.mat file. But the guide gives me how to use it in Matlab using MatconvNet Library. I want to implement the same thing in python. For which I am using Keras.

I have written the following code:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
model = VGG16(weights = "imagenet")
```

when I try to put `weights = "image-vgg-m-2408.mat"`
it gives me an exception.

Can someone help me, How to use the mat file model, weights in python to use this pre-trained model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you specify any `weights` which is not `imagenet`, it will just use keras `model.load_weights` to load it and I guess `image-vgg-m-2408.mat` is not a valid one that keras can load directly here.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/vgg16.py#L197

```
if weights == 'imagenet':
    if include_top:
        weights_path = keras_utils.get_file(
            'vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5',
            WEIGHTS_PATH,
            cache_subdir='models',
            file_hash='64373286793e3c8b2b4e3219cbf3544b')
    else:
        weights_path = keras_utils.get_file(
            'vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
            WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
            cache_subdir='models',
            file_hash='6d6bbae143d832006294945121d1f1fc')
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
    if backend.backend() == 'theano':
        keras_utils.convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)
elif weights is not None:
    model.load_weights(weights)
```

By default, keras will use imagenet as the default weight and the output class number will be 1000. But if you don't have other valid weight for this model, you can still leverage imagenet weight with a possible way:

- You can set include_top as False and use the VGG16 Conv output (without the final 3 FC layers) directly.

```
model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights = "imagenet")
```

https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/vgg16.py#L43

```
    include_top: whether to include the 3 fully-connected
        layers at the top of the network.
    weights: one of `None` (random initialization),
          'imagenet' (pre-training on ImageNet),
          or the path to the weights file to be loaded.
    classes: optional number of classes to classify images
        into, only to be specified if `include_top` is True, and
        if no `weights` argument is specified.
```

Comment: `image-vgg-m-2408.mat` is the modified model I want to use. How to use that in python than?

Comment: Then maybe consider to convert it to the format keras support and also make sure the model layer/operator names are the same as keras.applications.vgg16. Don't think it will be an easy work if you don't know the original model format and keras required format.

Comment: With google, I found this tutorial talking about convert MatconvNet model to keras : https://sefiks.com/2019/07/15/how-to-convert-matlab-models-to-keras/